# A count of user_pseudo_id is not same as a number shown in Firebase Dashboard

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I'm using Firebase and want to calculate daily active user count by BigQuery. But a number is different from one shown in dashboard.

I tried following query:

```
SELECT
  count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as dau
FROM
  `xxxx.events_*` as events
WHERE
1=1
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20190926'
```

Expected number is 8692 which is on Firebase dashboard. Actual output I got is 7815, much lower than dashboard count.

Comment: Does your table have any date/timestamp columns (`event_ts`) for example?  It is possible that Firebase is aggregating on that field, and not necessarily the table name.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried replacing 'count(distinct user_pseudo_id)' with 'count(event_timestamp)' but result was '1239228', completely wrong number unfortunately...

Comment: You misunderstand.  Your query is evaluating the table `xxx.events_20190926` (by appending the _TABLE_SUFFIX to the wildcard).  You will have events that happened on 20190926, but are not included in that table, they will come in the next day or the day after that.  Imagine an app user did something 2 days ago, but was offline, then today they connect to the internet and their events are uploaded.  Their `event_timestamp` will be from 2 days ago, but they would have today's _TABLE_SUFFIX.  Change your last line to `AND DATE(event_timestamp) = '2019-09-26'`.  You still will count user_ids.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, I changed my query a bit and the new query will be appended to next answer.  But the result was 7748, still quite different from the number 8692 shown on Firebase dashboard. Is my query correct? I have no idea what number Firebase counts as 'Active User'.

Comment: Changed query: `
SELECT
  count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as dau
FROM
  `xxxx.xxxx.events_*` as events
WHERE
1=1
AND DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) = '2019-09-26'
`

Comment: If your query has no additional filters, it seems weird that you would be under-reporting Firebase dashboard.  Your SQL seems to be in order now.  My only thoughts are Timezone differences (Firebase might report on your 'home' timezone while BQ events might be in UTC).  My other thought is that you might be missing some data.  You might pull several days of events, and see if there are any splits that look unusual (by hour, specific event counts, etc.).

Comment: The issue resolved. It was the value of 'Method of User Identification' (https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7663853?hl=en) that affected the number of DAU I got by the query. The default value was `By User-ID and device`. I changed it to `By device only` and now the number I got is as almost same as the one I see on the dashboard. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @KeiOikawa I have changed to By device only, but the result still not the same with the Firebase dashboard, Do you have any idea?

Comment: @LêQuangBảo May be you need to try the first query I wrote : `SELECT
  count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as dau
FROM
  `xxxx.events_*` as events
WHERE
1=1
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20190926'`.

Comment: The result is more different from firebase dashboard when use that query. When I use this query ```SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id)
FROM
  `xxxx.events_20190929`
WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'``` it return 1373 and the dashboard 1374.  Almost right, but Is there any way to get exact the same result